# Querying JSON with JSONPath or SelectTokens? With JSON.NET in C#

Tags: json, json.net, querying

I am trying to use the Newtonsoft.Json.Net in c#. The following is part of JSON file that I need to retrieve data out of:

```
{
    "video":{
        "local_recording_device":{
            "codecs":null
        },
        "preferred_string":"___PREFERRED___",
        "streams":{
            "99176901":{
                "id":"99176901",
                "name":"PTZ Camera",
                "site":"someone",
                "email":"someone@awebsite.com",
                "codec":"VP8 HD1 (720p)",
                "local":true,
                "screen":false,
                "fit_to_window":true,
                "stay_on_top":false,
                "layout":0,
                "native_width":1280,
                "native_height":720,
                "window_width":456,
                "window_height":254,
                "preferred":false,
                "local_recording":false,
                "device_id":"MJPEG Camera",
                "normalized_device_id":"MJPEGCamera",
                "shared_window_id":"MJPEG Camera",
                "enable":true,
                "big_location":"2",
                "x":347,
                "y":737,
                "window_id":"197302",
                "camera_id":null
            },
            "3091494011":{
                "id":"3091494011",
                "name":"Logitech Webcam C930e",
                "site":"Joe Smith",
                "email":"joe@awebsite.com",
                "codec":"VP8 Medium (CIF)",
                "local":false,
                "screen":false,
                "fit_to_window":true,
                "stay_on_top":false,
                "layout":0,
                "native_width":352,
                "native_height":288,
                "window_width":864,
                "window_height":702,
                "preferred":true,
                "local_recording":false,
                "enable":true,
                "big_location":"1",
                "x":204,
                "y":0,
                "window_id":"197296",
                "camera_id":null
            },
            "3798287599":{
                "id":"3798287599",
                "name":"Drive Camera",
                "site":"ASiteName",
                "email":"asitesame@awebsite.com",
                "codec":"VP8 HD1 (720p)",
                "local":true,
                "screen":false,
                "fit_to_window":true,
                "stay_on_top":false,
                "layout":0,
                "native_width":1280,
                "native_height":720,
                "window_width":456,
                "window_height":254,
                "preferred":true,
                "local_recording":false,
                "device_id":"Logitech Webcam C930e",
                "normalized_device_id":"LogitechWebcamC930e",
                "shared_window_id":"Logitech Webcam C930e",
                "enable":true,
                "big_location":"3",
                "x":814,
                "y":737,
                "window_id":"262822",
                "camera_id":null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, inside the JSON data is: "video", "streams" inside streams can be x amount of different streams (stream id's). The streams in "streams" (the long numbers) can change at anytime. In my example here there are three. I need to search through all streams in "streams" and see if any of them has a "email" that matches a particular email address. Each of the streams has a "email". If a email matches my supplied email address I need to check that streams "enable" to see if it's true or false.

Any help is appreciated in leading me in the right direction. I have not worked with a JSON data before.

Comment: Can you show the JSON you're working with and the expected output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) and [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to do the required query:

```
var testEmail = "someone@awebsite.com"; // The email for which we are searching

var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var streamQuery = obj.SelectTokens("video.streams.*")
    .Where(s => (string)s["email"] == testEmail);
var firstEnabled = streamQuery
    .Select(s => (bool?)s["enable"])
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The query returns a [nullable `bool`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-bool) that is `true` or `false` if the first stream for the desired email is enabled, or `null` if there is no stream for that email address.

Note that this returns the `enabled` state of the *first* stream matching the given email address.  If you want to know if *any* are enabled, do:

```
var anyEnabled = streamQuery.Any(s => (bool)s["enable"]);
```