# Read json value using C# without using Property

Tags: c#, json

I need to read the value of testCase.name for id 100000 from following JSON response string.

```
response = {
  "count": 2,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": 100000,
      "project": {
        "id": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd",
        "name": "MyTestProject",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/_apis/projects/MyTestProject"
      },      
      "testCase": { "name": "GetProjectTeamDetails" }
     }, 
    {
      "id": 100001,
      "project": {
        "id": "aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd",
        "name": "MyTestProject",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/MyOrg/_apis/projects/MyTestProject"
      },      
      "testCase": { "name": "QueueBuild" }      
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried the following codes but could not achieve:
Try1:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(response)
string testCaseName= (string)o["values"][0];
```

Try2:

```
 JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(response);
 string displayName = (string)jObject.SelectToken("testCase.name");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching for a specific JToken by name in a JObject hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645501/searching-for-a-specific-jtoken-by-name-in-a-jobject-hierarchy) and [Querying JSON with JSONPath or SelectTokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804299/querying-json-with-jsonpath-or-selecttokens-with-json-net-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
var testCaseName  = (string)jo.SelectToken($"$.value[?(@id=={idToSearch})].testCase.name");
```

**Update**

Base on your question in comment, you could find the ID with test case name using

```
jo.SelectTokens($"$.value[?(@testCase.name=='{nameToSearch}')].id")
```

Please note in this case, you would need to use `.SelectTokens` as there is chances of duplicates as give in the example in OP. You could get all the results or the first based on your requirement.

```
var idList  = jo.SelectTokens($"$.value[?(@testCase.name=='{nameToSearch}')].id")
                 .Select(x=> long.Parse(x.ToString()));
var onlyFirst = (long)jo.SelectTokens($"$.value[?(@testCase.name=='{nameToSearch}')].id")
                 .First();
```

Comment: THanks [AnuViswan], Is it also possible to get id using the test case name e.g I need to fetch Id where testCase.name is "GetProjectTeamDetails", I tried this: jObject.SelectToken($"$.value[?(@testCase.name=={"GetProjectTeamDetails"})].id"), but getting json exception

Comment: @SandeepDhamale Please check the update in answer. You would need to SelectTokens as there could be multiple matching results as per the example in OP

Answer (score 1):

You need to step through hierarchy.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var testCaseName = jObject.SelectToken("value[0].testCase.name").ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using `dynamic` keyword:

```
dynamic jt = JToken.Parse(response);
IEnumerable<dynamic> values = jt.value;
string name = values.FirstOrDefault(v => v.id == 100000)?.testCase.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have shown using `SelectToken`, which is fine - if you don't want to do that, you can still do it by accessing one property at a time:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        string testCase = (string) obj["value"][0]["testCase"]["name"];
        Console.WriteLine(testCase);
    }
}
```

In your Try1 you're using `values` instead of `value`, and you're stopping at the array - you're not asking for the `testCase` property, or the `name` property within that.

In your Try2 you're doing exactly the opposite - you're looking for `testCase.name` without selecting an element within the `value` array first.

As one third way, you could use dynamic typing:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        string testCase = obj.value[0].testCase.name;
        Console.WriteLine(testCase);
    }
}
```